# Force Aligner Trainers

Tags: computational-linguistics

I've been trying to use the Montreal Force Aligner in order to try and train a model for a language I've been working with for alignment of future data. However, I keep throwing a ton of errors, and after messing with the source code I realize that it doesn't even pass its own tests, so I'm hesitant to keep trying to use it. Does anyone know another trainer for some force aligner model?

Basically, I want to find a trainer and aligner that can do the following:

Trainer:

Input: Audio files (preferably wav) and phonetically transcribed TextGrids

Output: Some representation of model

Aligner:

Input: Precomputed Model, audio files (preferably wav), and word or sentence-level transcribed TextGrids (transcribed phonetically but no boundaries yet between phones, just between words or sentences)

Output: TextGrids with boundaries marking the phone boundaries

If anyone knows a good way of approaching this without starting from the ground up, that would be appreciated!